# Angularjs is not working after including dependancy on ui.bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

My html file is :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>example</title>

    <script src="angularjs"></script>
    <script src="bootstrapjs"></script>
    <script src="appjs"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_min_css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_responsive_min_css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appcss">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent" ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <div id="login" ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-show="is_new_user">
            The value of ng-show is : {{is_new_user}}
        </div>


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And my app.js file is as :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.is_new_user = false;
}]);

myApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.is_new_user = $scope.$parent.is_new_user;
}]);
```

But when I remove ui.bootstrap, my angularjs works (showing "The value of ng-sho is : false"). But when I add ui.bootstrap, it shows {{is_new_user}} in browser (means angularjs does not work).

I have also checked that all the js and css files are getting loaded in browser.

Comment: have you edited app.js ?

Comment: Hi @BlackSea, edited to what?

Comment: have you edited app.js file ?

Comment: the above shown index.html and app.js are the latest ones. But when I use 'ui.bootstrap', it shows {{is_new_user}} in browser. And when I remove 'ui.bootstrap', it show correct (false) and works properly. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Check browser console. There should be an error. I'm guessing Angular bootstrap is missing or something like this.

Comment: Thanks @DrahomírHanák. I checked and all the files mentioned are being included properly. Could you please tell me if I need to add any other css or js file in order to make ui.bootstrap work? Thanks.

Comment: @user2745266 have to load 2 files: Angular bootstrap and its templates - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower include both bootstrap-<version>.js and bootstrap-tpls-<version>.js